# Android recycler view position occurs index error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-mvvm, koin

I tried to control recycler view item visibility when i click button but it does not work

I'm using databinding in xml

this is error message

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 4

In my code, recycler view item has a constraintLayout and button

And constraintLayout has recycler view

I want to show constraintLayout  of item that has clicked button and hide other item's constraintLayout

The way that i tried to resolve this problem is to use previous position

When button is clicked, hide previous position's item and show current position's item

the code below is what i tried

this is clickListener in activity code

```
answerAdapter.onItemClickListener = object : QnaDetailAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onClick(
            view: View,
            position: Int,
            holder: QnaDetailAdapter.AnswerHolder
        ) {

            if (prePosition != -1)
                binding.recyclerViewAnswer[prePosition].comment_holder.visibility = View.GONE
            if (binding.recyclerViewAnswer[position].comment_holder.visibility == View.GONE) {
                binding.recyclerViewAnswer[position].comment_holder.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                prePosition = position
            } else {
                binding.recyclerViewAnswer[position-1].comment_holder.visibility = View.GONE
                prePosition = -1
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is adapter's onBindViewHodler

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AnswerHolder, position: Int) {

    if (onItemClickListener != null) {
        holder.btnComment.setOnClickListener { v ->
            onItemClickListener?.onClick(v, position, holder)
        }
    }

    holder.layout.recycler_view_comment.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    holder.layout.recycler_view_comment.setHasFixedSize(true)
    holder.layout.recycler_view_comment.adapter = adapter

    val item = answerList[position]
    holder.bind(item)
}
```

And this is AnswerHodler class

```
class AnswerHolder(private val binding: QnaDetailItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    val btnComment: Button = binding.btnComment
    val layout: ConstraintLayout = binding.commentHolder

    fun bind(item: Answer) {
        binding.item = item
    }
}
```

binding.comment is constraintLayout i touched on

thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

Rather thaan using`position`, use `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: I replaced position to holder.adapterPosition(kotlin way) but it still does not work. thank for your help